# When I am installing mpdf directory to generate pdf in php I'm getting this error

Tags: php, mpdf

In command prompt i am getting this error

> composer require mpdf/mpdf  In RequireCommand.php line 142:    file_put_contents(./composer.json): Failed to open stream: Permission denied

I've tried to installing but it is showing error

Answer (score 0):

Please check the write permissions of the directory in which you are attempting to install the library.

If permission is not granted, please grant permission.